# spring cloud discovery service - registering secure clients - healthCheckUrl

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I have all clients (eureka instances) running with https. I have configured my eureka clients as mentioned in https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/2.2.x/reference/html/#registering-a-secure-application

Everything in the config shown below works except the port information. Note that the config is clearly missing port information for all URLs, viz, statusPageUrl, healthCheckUrl and homePageUrl.

```
eureka:
  instance:
    nonSecurePortEnabled: false
    securePortEnabled: true
    **statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}/info**
    **healthCheckUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}/health**
    **homePageUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}/**
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER}
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
```

Since I have configured random port, I cannot hard code the port information in above urls. Could anyone please help me on this?

```
server:
  port: 0
```

Comment: https://blog.joshmlwood.com/eureka-spring-cloud-random-port/ might help you, also consider zuul or similar api gateway to access this

Comment: yes.. setting up the port programmatically is fine, how to access port number in application.yml?  healthCheckUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/health does not work, ${server.port} returns always zero